# Flutter is showing: Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Object for handle already exists: 8, null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException...)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-performance

Whenever I run my app this error comes up. Although, It does not affect any working of the app and the app works as I expect it to be. But I want to remove and know why this error occurs.
As I have read further this error was caused by Firebase performance.

Comment: run flutter run --verbose and post logs

Comment: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/7465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the problem faced in older versions of flutter. This issue was being tracked here: [github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/7465](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/7465) and this has been closed. **Upgrading your flutter to latest version will solve this issue.**